# Xamarin - Physical device deploy Color not correct

Tags: iphone, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm currently using Visual Studio Community on Windows (connected to Mac) with Xamarin.IOS 15.0.0.8 (the same version installed on MAC).
After updating Visual Studio to the version 16.11.4 and deploying the xamarin forms app to my physical device (Iphone X) i can notice that:
Shell.BackgroundColor is not blue and also the hamburgher icon menu not appear.

if i deploy the same app to the android emulator everything is working correctly.
[I attach this image to explain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEgGp.jpg)

What do you think ?

Answer (score 1):

According to my query, it seems that uikit has been updated in ios15. The default color is transparent.

I added in the FinishedLaunching method of **xxx.IOS->Appdelegate.cs**:

```
UINavigationBar.Appearance.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Blue;
```